# Big-time as a verb

Tags: word-meaning

In this sentence **big-time** is used as a verb:

> In short, polite people never **big-time** you; instead, they always make you feel big time.

[Source: 10 habits of remarkably polite people](http://www.inc.com/jeff-haden/10-habits-of-remarkably-polite-people.html)

What does **big-time** mean?

Comment: I agree with zone's answer in that it doesn't seem grammatically correct, and would also like to add a more common definition of 'big-time':
n. Informal
The most prestigious level of attainment in a competitive field: made it to the big time with his latest film.
[Source](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/big+time)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a (slang, informal) verb, to "big-time" would mean to act in a manner that projects the idea that one is the more important person or entity in the conversation or relationship or business deal. As an adjective, "big-time" would mean "important, significant, worthy".

> The company does not big-time its customers. It makes the customer feel
>   big-time.

An old-fashioned locution that means much the same thing is "to lord it over".

> The company does not lord it over the customer. They make the customer
>   feel like he's the king.

Comment: I had never heard "big time" as a verb before, but once I read the question, this answer is exactly what I got out of the context.